# Unit test with Karma

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I'm starting to learn about TDD and i would like an advice on how to test this basic function. 
I pass an argument in a function and if the argument is 'l' then the function return true.

```
function leave(response){
  if(response === 'l'){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}
```

I started like that, the test pass but this is not really what it should be(i use a var instead of function).

```
 describe('When the response is l, leave() is true', function() {
    it('should return true', function() {
      var leave = true
      expect(leave).toBe(true)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean. `expect(true).toBe(true)`should fail?!

Comment: i don't see how to "translate" the function into a test this is why i'm asking advice/help

Answer (score 1):

In TDD first the test should fail, then you  make your code to make the test pass.

Since you already have your function your test should pass.

So in your case your test should be something like:

```
 describe('When the response is l, leave() is true', function() {
    it('should return true', function() {
      var response = '1'
      expect(leave(response)).toBe(true)
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the function that you created. Your test should be like :

```
 describe('When the response is l, leave() is true', function() {
it('should return true', function() {
  var response = 6
  expect(leave(response)).toBe(true)
  });
 });
```

the test will fail now ;)